How to leave a blank page after List of Symbols
I want to add one blank pages with empty style after the List of Symbols. So far I have done this:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openany]{book}


% Include the preamble
\input{preamble}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\begin{document}

\input{chapters/coverpage.tex}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

\input{chapters/titlepage.tex}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

\frontmatter

\chapter*{Abstract}
\input{chapters/abstract.tex}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\chapter*{Declaration}
\input{chapters/declaration.tex}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\input{chapters/acknowledgements.tex}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage


\pdfbookmark[section]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\afterpage{\null\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage} % Add a blank page

\printnoidxglossary[type=symbols,style=long,title={List of Symbols}]
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\afterpage{\null\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage} % Add a blank page


\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{chapters/introduction.tex}

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\input{chapters/prelim}

\chapter{Conclusion}
\input{chapters/conclusion.tex}

\backmatter

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix Title}
\input{chapters/appendix.tex}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[
heading=bibintoc,
title={Bibliography}] 

\printacronyms[name=Abbreviations]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}

\printindex

\end{document}

But with this code I am getting two blank pages after List of Symbols: one completely blank followed by a blank page with header and footer.I have also tried to use \newpage but didn't work.
How can I solve this? Thanks.
Edit
Here is the minimal code. I need a blank page after toc. But when the toc is more than one page it's not giving any blank page:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openany]{book}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Include the preamble
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb} 
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    bindingoffset=0.2in,
    centering,
    marginparwidth=2in,
    textwidth=6.1in,
    marginparsep=2em,
    top=2.5cm,
    bottom=2.5cm,
%    showframe
]{geometry} 

\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%%%%%%%% Bibliography management %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,
style=alphabetic,
sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}

\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[program=makeindex,options=-s style.ist,columns=2,intoc=true]

%%%%%%%%%%% Glossaries and Acronyms %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[%
acronym,%
symbols,%
nogroupskip,%
nonumberlist,% Uncomment for not printing the page numbers at glossaries
%sort=use
]%
{glossaries-extra}
\makenoidxglossaries

\usepackage{acro}

%%
%%%Header styles
%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textbf{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textbf{\textit{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

%%
%%% Fancy Chapter Styles
%%
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}
%Options: Conny, Bjarne, Glenn, Lenny, Sonny, Rejne, Bjornstrup


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] % Coverpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

\frontmatter

\lipsum[1] % Titlepage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage


\chapter*{Abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\chapter*{Dedication}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\chapter*{Declaration}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\lipsum[2]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage


\pdfbookmark[section]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\glsxtrnewsymbol[sort={1},description={Set of all Natural numbers}]{N}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{N}}}

\printnoidxglossary[type=symbols,style=long,title={List of Symbols}]
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage


\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-6]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]


\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\backmatter

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix Title}
\lipsum[1]

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[
heading=bibintoc,
title={Bibliography}] 

\printacronyms[name=Abbreviations]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}

\printindex

\end{document}


Please note that no-one can test your code as we do not have the files you include. Additionally you \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations} will point to the wrong page if it is more than a page long

Just a guess: If you'd use \usepackage[cleardoublepage=empty]{scrextend} a single \cleardoublepage (without previous \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}) should be enough. But because you've not shown a minimal working example, I cannot test it. Maybe there is something in your chapters/*.tex files that also generates an empty page …

redefine cleardoublepage to insert an empty page and remove openany then you probably do not need any code in the body anymore. \makeatletter\renewcommand\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else     \hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}\makeatother

Off-topic: \frontmatter should usually be moved before the title page. If you open a book, you will find several pages before the first page that shows a page number. Nevertheless all these pages are usually counted.

@daleif I've added minimal code.

If I understand you correctly, you want a blank page after the table of contents, regardless of whether the table of contents ends on an even or odd page. You can always add an unconditionally empty page using:
\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\null\clearpage

Notes:

If you don't want to flush all floats, you can use \newpage instead of \clearpage (but usually if you want an empty page, you want to print all floats before).
Instead of \null you can alternatively use, e.g., \mbox{}, \nobreakspace, ~, or some other invisible content. The (invisible) content is needed, because otherwise consecutive \newpage/\clearpage are ignored.

So in your case:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openany]{book}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Include the preamble
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb} 
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    bindingoffset=0.2in,
    centering,
    marginparwidth=2in,
    textwidth=6.1in,
    marginparsep=2em,
    top=2.5cm,
    bottom=2.5cm,
%    showframe
]{geometry} 

\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%%%%%%%% Bibliography management %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,
style=alphabetic,
sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}

\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[program=makeindex,options=-s style.ist,columns=2,intoc=true]

%%%%%%%%%%% Glossaries and Acronyms %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[%
acronym,%
symbols,%
nogroupskip,%
nonumberlist,% Uncomment for not printing the page numbers at glossaries
%sort=use
]%
{glossaries-extra}
\makenoidxglossaries

\usepackage{acro}

%%
%%%Header styles
%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textbf{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textbf{\textit{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

%%
%%% Fancy Chapter Styles
%%
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}
%Options: Conny, Bjarne, Glenn, Lenny, Sonny, Rejne, Bjornstrup


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] % Coverpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

\frontmatter

\lipsum[1] % Titlepage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage


\chapter*{Abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\chapter*{Dedication}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\chapter*{Declaration}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\lipsum[2]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage


\pdfbookmark[section]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\null\clearpage% add empty page

\glsxtrnewsymbol[sort={1},description={Set of all Natural numbers}]{N}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{N}}}

\printnoidxglossary[type=symbols,style=long,title={List of Symbols}]
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage


\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-6]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]


\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\lipsum[1]

\backmatter

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix Title}
\lipsum[1]

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[
heading=bibintoc,
title={Bibliography}] 

\printacronyms[name=Abbreviations]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}

\printindex

\end{document}

